# Error estimation for spline interpolation

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods

Can you please indicate a reference for the proof of the fact that the error when interpolating a $C^4$ function by a cubic spline is bounded by $Ch^4\sup_{[x_{i},x_{i+1}]} |f''''(x)|$?

Comment: Tried google? Because it seems full of results of articles about it. (I didn't check them )

Comment: Of course I tried google... In every article I saw it it was without proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm 90% sure you can find it in deBoor's book "A Practical Guide to Splines".

Here's [a link to Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387953663).

I checked, and equation (12) on page 55 of the 2001 edition says that:
$$
\left\Vert g - I_4g \right\Vert \le 
\frac{1}{16}\left\vert \tau \right\vert^4 \left\Vert g^{(4)} \right\Vert
$$

Here $I_4g$ is the complete cubic spline interpolant of $g$ on the mesh $\tau$.

The result was improved by Hall and Meyer, Journal of Approximation Theory, Vol. 16, 1976, pp.105-122. They showed that the constant $\frac{1}{16}$ could be replaced by $\frac{5}{384}$, and that this constant is best possible.

Comment: Is there a result available for a general spline (not necessarily cubic)?  If not, then how would one go about deriving it?  Could one obtain tighter limits if one was looking to interpolate a specific function,  say, $\exp(x)$?  Many thanks

Comment: I expect so, but I don’t know for sure. The book by de Boor would be a good place to start looking. Norms of derivatives typically appear in these bounds. If you have a fairly simple specific function in mind, you should be able to get a tight bound on its norm, and this will give you a tight bound on the approximation error.  There are special-purpose approximation techniques for common special functions like sin, exp, log. Look up “CORDIC’.

Answer (score 4):

In Douglas Arnold's notes: [A Concise Introduction to Numerical Analysis](http://www.ima.umn.edu/~arnold/597.00-01/nabook.pdf).

A proof of error bound is given for Cubic spline from Page 31 exploiting the commutative diagram, the notation $M^k_s(\mathcal{T})$ just means degree $k$ piecewise polynomial and $s$-continuously differentiable.