# Precision in Cubic spline interpolation

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, interpolation, cubics, spline

I am working on cubic spline interpolation with set of data points from CAD with following steps:

- Form piecewise spline equations between points. cubic equation :
  $ ax^3 + bx^2 +cx + d = P(x) $
- Form first derivative equations at interior points
- Form Second derivative equations at interior points
- Set Second derivative equations at exterior points to zero

[Cubic_Spline with data points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OVz0.jpg)

Attached is the workout on spreadsheet with formulas and the calculations as follows,

[Google spreadsheet with interpolation calculation](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_Y0YDhXFYHOHKHTigQZBrbzW3kfMYgBmti21PL-E3Jo/edit?usp=sharing)

1. Section1: Contains input data points for interpolation
2. Section 2: spline equations in matrix form
3. Section 3: Interpolation results for test points
4. Section 4: Graphical representation of spline (Points marked in
   Green are input data points and marked in Red are test points used
   to test in section 3)

**Query:**
But interpolation result for the test points in section 3 yields loss of precision of around 1 to 2 mm. Am I making mistakes in procedures or calculation? or do the interpolation always results in loss of precision?

If someone could throw light on this, would be appreciated.

Comment: A qubic spline is nothing but a fit of your data-points to a qubic equation. Unless the curve the data-points represent happens to be a cubic polynomial (or lower) it will not be exact for other points. Also note that the difference you find is like $0.01 - 0.1\%$ - that is pretty accurate imo.

Comment: Related questions (error estimates for cubic splines): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/418523/error-estimation-for-spline-interpolation http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1065355/natural-cubic-spline-interpolation-error-estimate

Comment: where do you get the values for "Expected(X)"?

Comment: @fang: Expected(X) are the values from CAD data, which is shown in the picture with red colour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cubic spline interpolation thru points will pass thru the given points exactly (subject to numeric errors though). But in general it will have deviation when compared against the original curve (from which you sample the points) except at those interpolated points. The fact that you are having a 0.1% deviation suggests that the cubic spline you found is a very good approximation to the original curve.

In fact, if you use the interpolated points (instead of the test points) in step 3, you should still find "loss of precision" while the difference should be theoretically zero. Such "loss of precision" comes from doing the numeric solving of the linear equation set. Such numeric errors could become notably large when your matrix value is extremely big (or small), such as in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed expanation