# Order of accuracy for cubic spline interpolation

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, interpolation, computational-mathematics

What is the order of accuracy of the cubic spline interpolation method? I have been looking around but not sure if I am getting the right idea. Does it have fourth-order accuracy? How should one derive the result? Any references would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is all covered in Carl de Boor’s book entitled “A Practical Guide to Splines”. Yes, the approximation is fourth order.

Or, see formula (1) in [these notes.](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eamos/412/lecture-notes/lecture12.pdf)

Or look at the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/418523/error-estimation-for-spline-interpolation?noredirect=1&lq=1).