# define n for a natural cubic spline

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, interpolation

How to define it? Given an interval [0,1] with n+1 uniformly distributed nodes and f(x)=sin(2pi*x).
What must n be for the natural cubic spline that belongs to be valid? [image]

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1065355/natural-cubic-spline-interpolation-error-estimate, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/418523/error-estimation-for-spline-interpolation